# Passing a variable to a subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to cut the first n lines of a file off a file, I calculate n and assign that value to myvariable

```
command = "tail -n +"myvariable" test.txt >> testmod.txt"
call(command)
```

I've imported call from subprocess. But I get a syntax error at myvariable.

Comment: You get a syntax error because you that's not valid Python code.

Comment: Your concatenation should be done this way: `cmd = "..." + myvar + "..."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things wrong here:

1. Your string concatenation syntax is all wrong; that's not valid Python. You probably wanted to use something like:

   ```
   command = "tail -n " + str(myvariable) + " test.txt >> testmod.txt"
   ```

   where I assume that `myvariable` is an integer, not a string already.

   Using string formatting would be more readable here:

   ```
   command = "tail -n {} test.txt >> testmod.txt".format(myvariable)
   ```

   where the `str.format()` method will replace `{}` with the string version of `myvariable` for you.
2. You need to tell `subprocess.call()` to run that command through the shell, because you are using `>>`, a shell-only feature:

   ```
   call(command, shell=True)
   ```

Comment: @Gar: you could also use a list argument: `rc = call(["tail", "-n", str(myvariable), "test.txt"], stdout=open('testmod.txt', 'a'))`